# Visual studio community 2017 Срок действия лицензии истёк

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Истёк срок действия лицензии в visual studio community 2017,выдаёт следующее[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Community ведь позиционируется как бесплатная для всех и каждого,какая лицензия?
Как можно исправить?

Пробовал выходить,заново входить в аккаунт,создавать новый аккаунт,перезагружать устройство.
Переустановка VS не вариант,трафик дорог

Comment: Ссылка "проверить наличие обновленной лицензии" не помогает?

Comment: @PashaPash нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена обновлением студии при помощи утилиты vs_installer,которую можно найти в той же папке,где и установлена Visual Studio

Comment: Помогает иногда смена учётной записи, для тех кто страдает от лицензионных глюков студии 2017